# Spamassasin reports HTML_FONT_TINY with huge penalty, what is it?

Tags: html, spam-prevention, newsletter, mail

**Update**

The authors of the plugin suggested that it is a [false positive](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/spamassasin-reports-html_font_tiny?replies=1).

---

I am using [MailPoet](http://www.mailpoet.com/) in a Wordpress installation to send newsletters.

In an effort to validate the chances a newsletter has to be characterized as 'spam', I sent an email to the ['Newsletters spam test by mail-tester.com'](https://www.mail-tester.com/).

There, I see an entry with a huge penalty:

> `-1.499        HTML_FONT_TINY      HTML_FONT_TINY`

The links to the relevant spamassassin pages [do not provide any information](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/HTML_FONT_TINY).

The same goes for the [spamassassin tests page](http://spamassassin.apache.org/tests_3_1_x.html).

Googling it a bit, seems like it is reffering to a small font size. However, the smaller font size I have set is 14px. This is not a size one would call 'tiny'.

How could I fix this?

I have also posted [a report](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/spamassasin-reports-html_font_tiny?replies=1) to the relevant plugin pages.

Comment: Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo and so forth have much better checkers than those online tests, so it looks like your getting a false postive. Check using another checker.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to see the source of an e-mail sent by MailPoet.

Comment: Indeed, I will try to do so. I have also reported it to their [issues page.](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/spamassasin-reports-html_font_tiny?replies=1)

Comment: How did you go with this @raratiru?

Comment: @TimMalone I have ignored it as a false-positive. This is what the author of the MailPoet plugin has suggested as a solution.

Comment: Excellent. Glad you solved it. Thanks for posting it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author of the plugin [suggested](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/spamassasin-reports-html_font_tiny?replies=1), this can be treated as a false-positive.

> Our SpamAssassin checks on mail-tester trigger a lot of
>   false-positives, please ignore them.